# Slim Framework Containter

Tags: php, framework, slim

Из документации Slim  нашел контроллерный роутер, а когда вызываю его в коде, мне выдает ошибку. Помогите с проблемой, пожалуйста

> **Slim Application Error
>   A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.**

```php
class MyController {
    protected $ci;

    // Constructor
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci) {
        $this->ci = $ci;
    }

    public function method1($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->ci->get('');
    }
}
```

Подключил так

```php
$app->get('/method1', '\MyController:method1');
$app->run();
```